Connect-4 on $h*l$ grid is winning for player 1?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four
It is known player 1 has a winning strategy for the original game.
The original game has a grid with hight (or row) $6$ and length (or column) $7$ and thus $42$ squares.
Is connect-4 played on a given rectangular grid with hight $h$ and length $l$ always winning for the first player with optimal play, if $hl > 41$ ?
If not, what are the conditions for $hl$ such that the first player always has a winning strategy ?

According to this, the second player wins on an $8\times8$ board. I doubt there is a simple description of winning board sizes.

Also, why do you expect that the answer should only depend on $hl$, instead on $h$ and $l$ separately? For example, a $1\times42$ board is clearly a draw, whereas the standard board is a win for the first player.

The state of the art (2024) seems to be https://github.com/ChristopheSteininger/c4?tab=readme-ov-file#outcome, the general game is not solved yet.

@anankElpis I just wanted to avoid small grids.

If I understand the comments correctly there is not much math involved and all results are the result of big searches ?

Yes, strategy stealing will probably give nothing here, and exhibiting an optimal strategy in the general case seems completely out of reach for the moment. Out of these strategies, I'm unaware of other theoretical tools that proved useful in solving such combinatorial games.
